# Editor.java assistance

Tags: java

I have this program called Editor.java it is almost finish but i need to finish public void doRun(String Line). How Run should work is when you type RUN it will start the program executing at the lowest numbered line it can find. If RUN is followed by a number like 35 it  should begin at the first line number it finds that is greater than or equal to the specified  number. For example if I typed in :

```
5 LET A = 5
10 PRINT A
20 LET X = 10
30 LET Y = 20
40 PRINT X + Y
50 LET Z = X + Y * 2
60 PRINT Z
70 GOTO 90
80 LET Z = 10
90 PRINT X Y Z
100 LET P = 80
110 IF (Z > 20) THEN LET P = 10
120 PRINT P
RUN 15
```

The Output should be:

```
X + Y = 30.0
Z : 50.0 
X Y Z : 10.0 20.0 50.0 
P : 10.0
```

This is the code I developed so far If anyone could assist it would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Editor
{
  EditLL list;
  HashTable commands;
  HashTable variables;
  final static String comm[] = {"LOAD", "SAVE", "RESEQUENCE", "LIST", "QUIT", "EXIT", "LET", "PRINT", "INPUT", "RUN"}; 

  public Editor()
  {
    list = new EditLL();
    commands = new HashTable();
    variables = new HashTable();
    for (int i = 0; i < comm.length; i++)
    {
      commands.insert(comm[i], (double)i);
    }
  }

  public boolean processLine(String line) throws IOException
  {
    boolean retval = true;
    line = trimLeadingWhitespace(line);
    int last = line.indexOf(' ');
    String initial = line;
    if (last >= 0)
      initial = line.substring(0, last);
    if (last >= 0)
    {
      line = line.substring(last);
      line = trimLeadingWhitespace(line);
    }
    else
      line = "";
    if (isInt(initial))
    {
      int lineNum = Integer.parseInt(initial);
      list.insert(lineNum, line);
    }
    else
    {
      int key = (int)commands.getValue(initial);
      switch(key)
      {
case 0: this.load(line);
        break;
case 1: this.save(line);
        break;
case 2: list.resequence(10);
        break;
case 3: System.out.println(this.list);
        break;
case 4:
case 5: retval = false;
        break;
case 6: doLet(line);  // line after the word let
        break;
case 7: print(line, variables);
        break;
case 8: input(line);
        break;
case 9: doRun(line);

default: System.out.println("Unknown command " + initial);
      }
    }
    return retval;
  }

  public void doRun(String line) // Need Help here
  {
    int linenum;
    int temp;
    line = trimLeadingWhitespace(line);
    line = trimTrailingWhitespace(line);
  }


  public void input(String line)
  {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    line = trimLeadingWhitespace(line);
    line = trimTrailingWhitespace(line);
    System.out.print(line + "=?");
    variables.insert(line, kb.nextDouble());
  } 

  public void doLet(String line)
  {
    int last = line.indexOf('=');
    String lhs = line.substring(0, last);
    String lhs2 = "";
    int i = 0;
    char c = lhs.charAt(i);
    while(!Character.isWhitespace(c))
    {
      lhs2 += c;
      i++;
      c = lhs.charAt(i);
    }
    line = line.substring(last+1);
    double value = Infix.evaluate(line, variables);
    variables.insert(lhs2, value);
  }

  public void print(String line, HashTable variables)
  {
    line = trimLeadingWhitespace(line);
    double value = Infix.evaluate(line, variables);
    System.out.println(line + " = " + value);
  }


  public void load(String line) throws IOException
  {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(line));
    list = new EditLL();
    int nextLine = 0;

    while(in.hasNext())
    {
      nextLine += 10;
      list.insert(nextLine, in.nextLine());
    }
    in.close();
  }

  public void save(String line) throws IOException
  {
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File(line));
    String nextline = list.getFirst();
    while (!nextline.equals(""))
    {
      out.println(nextline);
      nextline = list.getNext();
    }
    out.close();
  }


  public static boolean isInt(String s)
  {
    boolean retval;
    try
    {
      Integer.parseInt(s);
      retval = true;
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
      retval = false;
    }
    return retval;
  } 

  public static String trimLeadingWhitespace(String s)
  {
    String retval = "";
    int i = 0;
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    while (Character.isWhitespace(c))
    {
      i++;
      c = s.charAt(i);
    } 
    for (int j = i; j < s.length(); j++)
    {
      retval += c = s.charAt(j);
    }

    return retval;
  }

  public static String trimTrailingWhitespace(String s)
  {
    String retval = "";

    int lastNonW = -1;
    char c;
    for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++)
    {
      c = s.charAt(j);
      if (!Character.isWhitespace(c))
      {
        lastNonW = j;
      }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j <= lastNonW; j++)
      retval += s.charAt(j);
    return retval;
  }
 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException // Help Here
  {
    Editor ed = new Editor();
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line;

    do
    {

      line = kb.nextLine().toUpperCase();
    }while (ed.processLine(line));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have bigger problems: You haven't implemented GOTO.

If you implement GOTO, then you can solve your problem by having a virtual instruction at the beginning of the instruction list that is a `0 GOTO 35`, or whatever the user types in.

Oh, and a proper GOTO will need to be able to jump back...

Welcome to StackOverflow!